# Selenium cannot find elements

Tags: python, selenium, sap-business-technology-platform

I try to automate retrieving data from "SAP Business Client" using Python and Selenium.
Since I cannot find the element I wanted even though I am sure it is correct, I printed out the html content with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

EDGE_PATH = r"C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\WPy64-3940\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver"
service = Service(executable_path=EDGE_PATH)
options = Options()
options.use_chromium = True
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
cc_driver = webdriver.Edge(service = service, options=options)

cc_driver.get('https://saps4.sap.XXXX.de/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/FioriLaunchpad.html#Z_APSuche-display')
sleep(5)
cc_html = cc_driver.page_source

cc_content = soup(cc_html, 'html.parser')
print(cc_content.prettify())
cc_driver.close()
```

Now I am just surprised, because the printed out content is different than from firefox "inspect" function. For example, I can find the word "Nachname" from the firefox html content but not such word exists in the printed out html content from the code above:
[image]

[image]

Have someone an idea, why the printed out content is different?
Thank you for any help... Gunardi

Comment: Javascript is probably operating on the page after it is initially rendered.

Comment: Hey @takendarkk , is there a way to still get the html element I needed?

Comment: @gunardilin https://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Possibly because of headless mode. execute the code again with comment this `options.add_argument("headless")` and check whether you are getting the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

the code you get from selenium is a the code without javascript process on it, then you shoul get the code  from javascript using selenium interaction with javascipt,
`String javascript = "return arguments[0].innerHTML"; String pageSource=(String)(JavascriptExecutor)driver) .executeScript(javascript, driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")`enter code here`)); pageSource = "<html>"+pageSource +"</html>"; System.out.println(pageSource);`